# Unable to get a decorator to take a parameter

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a decorator that works with or without a parameter. I have this so far:

```
def logged_in(func=None, *, permissions=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(logged_in, permissions=None)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable:
        nonlocal permissions
        if not g.get('user'):
            response.unauthorized()
        if permissions:
            if type(permissions) == str:
                permissions = [permissions]
            if not g.user.admin and not bool(
                set(g.user.permissions) & set(permissions)
            ):
                response.forbidden()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

I'm calling it as

```
@logged_in(permissions=['asdf'])
def my_method():
```

However, I keep getting an error at `if permissions:` that permissions isn't set. I'm using [a guide](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/9/defining_a_decorator_that_takes_an_optional_argument/example.py) though I've seen the same style of code written in many places.

Comment: Your function `wrapper` contains an assignment `permissions = ...` so therefore `permissions` is interpreted as a local variable; either you need to write `nonlocal permissions` at the top of `wrapper`, or do the reassignment in the outer function, or do the reassignment to a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

`permissions` is defined in an outer scope (`logged_in`) and assigned to in an inner scope (`wrapper`). In Python, we have to declare such cases as [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal-stmt)

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable:
    nonlocal permissions
    ...
```

Comment: Is this the right way to do it? None of the tutorial I've found have done this, so I'm confused if my code is wrong, or if there's a different solution I should be using.

Comment: `nonlocal` is definitely idiomatic Python. The "odd" thing is probably that you're reassigning to `permissions`, which basic tutorials may not be doing

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you mean by reassisnging here. I take it in as a param, but that's it? I'm using https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/9/defining_a_decorator_that_takes_an_optional_argument/example.py

Comment: Later in the function, you do `permissions = [permissions]`, which is why you need `nonlocal`. If you don't assign to the parameter, then it's fine without.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. But it fails before that. In fact, I just added nonlocal, and permissions is just always None, even when I try `@logged_in(permissions=['asdf'])`

Comment: Right, it's complicated. Python detects (at parse time) that you're assigning to it and creates a position for it in the function's memory, and since you haven't assigned to that position yet, you get an error the first time you *read* the variable. Frankly, it's awkward and `nonlocal` is an exceedingly large and not very pretty band-aid.

Comment: With `nonlocal`, however, it should be working. If that still doesn't fix it, I recommend editing the question to indicate what's going wrong now.

Comment: I've edited the question with the updated code.

Comment: I see now that it looks like you're expecting decorators to place the function in the first argument position when called, but that's not how they work. See [PEP318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) (specifically, the section titled Current Syntax). You'll need to return an inner function if you want to allow the decorator to take arguments.